# how to add a static field on odoo report without looping?

Tags: html, css, report, odoo, qweb

[image]I need to print a timesheet report for each employee, and I need to display the employee name at the header not on the column cells because it will be repeated in every row and I don't need that

I tried to use < t-foreach > but it displays the name to much

```
 <template id="19011.employee">
     <t t-call="web.html_container">
         <t t-call="web.external_layout">
             <div class="page">
                 <div class="text-center">
                     <h2> <strong>TIME SHEET</strong>
                     </h2>
                     <h2>
                         <tr t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                             <span t-field="o.employee_id" />
                         </tr>
                     </h2>
                 </div>
                 <table class="table table-condensed" bgcolor="#875A7B">
                     <tr>
                         <th> check in</th>
                         <th> check out</th>
                         <th> Total</th>
                     </tr>
                     <tr t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                         <td>
                             <t t-esc="o.check_in" />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <t t-esc="o.check_out" />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <t t-esc="o.total" />
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr bgcolor="#875A7B">
                         <td align="center"> <strong> Total Hours</strong></td>
                         <td></td>
                         <td>
                             <strong t-esc="sum([o.total for o in docs])" />
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
             </div>
         </t>
     </t>
 </template>
```

Comment: can you put an image that shows what you need exactly, you a tool to draw how the report should look we didn't understand exactly how the report should look like, and do it for two employee it's better

Comment: i added a screenshot

Comment: You want the report to look like that or you want to see the employee only one time then after the name you see the list of his check in check out. after that the name of the second employee and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay let try a simple solution if all time sheet is for one employee, you can show its name by accessing the first record.

```
        <div class="text-center">
             <h2> <strong>TIME SHEET</strong>
             </h2>
             <h2>
                   <t t-if="docs">
                     <!-- in case employee don't have any attending records you dont want to get index error -->
                     <span t-field="docs[0].employee_id" />
                   </t>
             </h2>
         </div>
```

If the time sheet have more than one employee then it needs more work than this, and there is multiple solution for that too.

I don't know if accessing the first `record` by `index` will cause a problem with `t-field` if it does try to set a `variable`.

```
            <t t-set="first_record" t-value="docs[0]"/>
            <span t-field="first_record.employee_id" />
```

Comment: thank you very much dear , tow solution working well by getting the first record 
if you can give me a solution for if there is more than one employee you will make a big favor to me

Answer (score 0):

If there is more than one record what I love to do hire is group
`records` by `employee` using `dictionary`. but I love to do this 
with `python`. so all I have to do is create `method` in `attendance`
to loop through records and create a `dictionary` then call this 
method in the `report` and print that `dictionary` with two loops.

```py
  @api.mutli
  def group_py_employee(self):
    """ group record by employee."""
    result = {}
    for rec in self:
        if rec.employee_id in result:
            result[rec.employee_d].append(rec)
        else:
            result[rec.empoloyee_ids] = [rec,]

    return result
```

And in the report if you want to show employe par page:

```xml
<template id="19011.employee">
 <t t-call="web.html_container">
     <t t-call="web.external_layout">
         <!-- call the method to get the dictionary -->
         <t t-set="result"  t-value="docs.group_py_employee()/>
         <t t-foreach="result.items()" t-as="time_sheet">
             <!-- here first element is the employee record, second is it's attends records -->
             <div class="page">
                 <div class="text-center">
                     <h2> <strong>TIME SHEET</strong>
                     </h2>
                     <h2>
                         <!-- show employee in index 0 it's record of employee not attendance -->
                        <span t-field="time_sheet[0].name" />
                     </h2>
                 </div>
                 <table class="table table-condensed" bgcolor="#875A7B">
                     <tr>
                         <th> check in</th>
                         <th> check out</th>
                         <th> Total</th>
                     </tr>
                     <!-- second element is list of attendance-->
                     <tr t-foreach="time_sheet[1]" t-as="o">
                         <td>
                             <t t-esc="o.check_in" />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <t t-esc="o.check_out" />
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <t t-esc="o.total" />
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr bgcolor="#875A7B">
                         <td align="center"> <strong> Total Hours</strong></td>
                         <td></td>
                         <td>
                             <strong t-esc="sum([o.total for o in time_sheet[1]])" />
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
             </div>
        </t>
     </t>
 </t>
```

Note I forget the name of the `model` that contains the time sheet of the employee
 you should `inherit` that `model` and add this method  `group_py_employee` Hope you get the idea.